# Session dying when using curl from command line

Tags: java, session, authentication, curl, spark-java

I mad a simple java web app using [sparkjava](http://sparkjava.com/).  It fields GET and POST requests.  I made my own simple authentication script, which authenticates the user using the secret password and stores the username in the session:

```
    /*
    Make sure authenticated
    */
    before((req, res) -> {
        boolean authenticated = false;
        if ( req.session().attribute("user") != "casumo_user" ) {
            try{
                if (req.queryParams("secret").equals(System.getenv().get("SECRET"))){
                    authenticated = true;
                    req.session().attribute("user","casumo_user");
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                halt(401, "{\"error\":\"Please Authenticate.\"}");
            }
        }else{
            authenticated = true;
        }

        if (!authenticated) {
            halt(401, "{\"error\":\"Please Authenticate.\"}");
        }
    });
```

I was using the [Postman Add-on for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), and this was working fine.  I would authenticate once, and the server would keep my session alive for subsequent requests.

The problem is I wanted to use curl to make the same requests, but the session was not staying alive from one request to another.

For example, first I use this command:

```
curl -s -L --data "secret=secret_password" url/auth | jsonpp
```

> { "msg": "Authenticated! You can now make requests." }

But then making a sebsequent GET request proves that the session is not preserved/

```
curl -s -L url/films | jsonpp
```

> { "error": "Please Authenticate." }

Using the Postman App would allow me to make GET and POST requests for quite some time after authenticating 1 time.  Is it possible to do this using curl from the command line like I have here?  Or is my authentication system not robust enough to use curl from the command line?

Thanks!

[The project is on GitHub.](https://github.com/jefferythewind/movie_rental)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `curl` to store cookies between calls, you need to tell it to do so.

Check out the `--cookie` and `--cookie-jar` options.

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -s -L --data "secret=secret_password"
# then
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt -s -L url/films
```

The `--cookie-jar` option tells curl to write any cookies it received to the file when the request ends, and the `--cookie` option instructs it to read cookies from that file for issuing requests.

That should allow you to log in, and then use the cookies to re-establish the session on subsequent requests.

`curl --help` and `man curl` are your friends!

Comment: I have been literally digging for hours for this, worked!

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the great @drew010 answer, you can also use both `--cookie` and `--cookie-jar` together if you need to read and (also) write/update the cookie.

Example of bash script using cURL, reading and writing cookies, and storing them in the `/temp` folder (to keep your local folder clean):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "## SUBMITTING..."; sleep 0.5;
echo "## SERVER RESPONSE:";
echo ""; sleep 0.5;

curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8080/web-service/path \
  --cookie /tmp/cookie.txt \
  --cookie-jar /tmp/cookie.txt \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \

echo "";
echo "";
```